# Forum with a point system

Tags: smf

How can I setup a forum with a point system which my users can get their points higher by simply posting more articles, watching related videos and referring others. I do not care which form system it is; vbulleting, smf or another. I just wanna know if it's possible to do. Thank you!

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. It's very simply.. you need to change a little bit your php code and mysql structure.

php code: on posting query, you need to add points for each post/topic. For example

```
INSERT into posting (user_id,title,subject,points) values ('1','lorem ipsum','lorem ipsum','10');
```

mysql code:

```
alter table posting add points varchar(20);
```

php code (profil page): you need also to create a query in the profil page, to sum all user points.

It works on vbulletin, phpbb and smf (i don't know on other platforms)